# Parameterize join conditions in pyspark

Tags: join, pyspark, conditional-statements

I would like to perform a left join in pyspark that does the following.

Given a table X with all rows and columns informed:

| Column A | ... | Column N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cell | cell | cell |
| cell | cell | cell |

And a Table Y with some rows with a default value, let's say "*":

| Column A | ... | Column N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cell | cell | * |
| * | cell | cell |

I would like to join to perform a joined = x.join(y, on=[], how = 'left') so that for each row it takes into account the columns without * element.

I have come up with a solution where I first set the conditions as follows:

conditions = F.when(Y.columnA != '* ')&(Y.columnB == '* ')&(Y.columnC != '* '), (X.columnA == Y.columnA)&(X.columnC == Y.columnC)
.when(Y.columnA == '* ')&(Y.columnB == '* ')&(Y.columnC != '* '), (X.columnC == Y.columnC)

joined= X.join(Y, conditions, how = 'left')

The issue with this solution is that as the number the conditions increase, it becomes very tedious to write all the number of possible combinations.

Is it possible to parameterize this problem?

Comment: Did not understand what your `conditions` variable does, could you explain it?

Comment: I define the condition the join must use. I expanded the example. Basically, if the column has in a row the '* ' element, it will be omited in the join.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the columns which do not contain `*` using the below code

```
conditions = [c for c, v in df.select([
    F.count(F.when(F.col(c).contains('*'), 1)).alias(c) for c in df.columns
]).first().asDict().items() if not v]
```

Then you can use those columns to join directly like so,

```
joined= X.join(Y, conditions, how = 'left')
```